# Why does the animation state change work in one script and not in the other?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, animation

The first script uses the AnimationClip.name to get a string name to change the animation states, and it works perfectly.

```
{
[Header ("Animation")]
[SerializeField] AnimationClip active;
[SerializeField] AnimationClip end;

[Header ("Fire Projectile")]
[SerializeField] float activeTime;

string currentState;
Animator anim;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void SetToActive()
{
    ChangeAnimationState(active.name);
    Invoke("PortalEnd", activeTime);
}

void PortalEnd()
{
    ChangeAnimationState(end.name);
}

void DestroyPortal()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

public void ChangeAnimationState(string newState)
{
    // Stop the same animation from interrupting itself.
    if (currentState == newState) return;

    // Play the desired animation.
    anim.Play(newState);

    // Reassign the current state to the new state.
    currentState = newState;
}
```

}

and in the inspector I just drag in the desired animation clip
[image]

However, in the second script, I'm trying to use the same method to get the animation clip string names, but it's not working.

```
{
[Header ("Components")]
[SerializeField] Transform target;
[SerializeField] Transform attackPos;
[SerializeField] GameObject attackPortal;
[SerializeField] float distanceToTarget;
[SerializeField] float attackRange;
[SerializeField] float attackCooldown;

[Header ("Animations")]
[SerializeField] AnimationClip move;
[SerializeField] AnimationClip attack;
[SerializeField] AnimationClip die;

string currentState;
Animator anim;
Rigidbody2D rb;
Enemy enemy;
public bool attackingTarget;
bool dead;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    enemy = GetComponent<Enemy>();
    target = FindObjectOfType<Player>().transform;
}

void Update()
{
    distanceToTarget = Vector2.Distance(this.transform.position, target.position);
    if (distanceToTarget <= attackRange && !attackingTarget && !dead)
    {
        attackingTarget = true;
        AttackTarget();
    }
    if (!dead && GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().health == 0)
    {
        dead = true;
        ChangeAnimationState(die.name);
    }
}

void AttackTarget()
{
    ChangeAnimationState(attack.name);
    enemy.enabled = false;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (0,0);
}

void SummonPortal()
{
    GameObject portal = Instantiate(attackPortal, attackPos);
    portal.transform.parent = this.transform;
}

void ReturnToMoving()
{
    ChangeAnimationState(move.name);
    enemy.enabled = true;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y);
    Invoke("AttackAgain", attackCooldown);
}

void AttackAgain()
{
    attackingTarget = false;
}

public void ChangeAnimationState(string newState)
{
    // Stop the same animation from interrupting itself.
    if (currentState == newState) return;

    // Play the desired animation.
    anim.Play(newState);

    // Reassign the current state to the new state.
    currentState = newState;
}
```

}

[image]

For some reason it works when I type out the string name, but using this method, it just gives me an error.
[image]

I've been working on this for so long, and I just don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: My guess would be the "CultistLv." in the name when actually its 1Move for example.

Comment: PS Id bet some debugging would answer that question

Comment: It doesn't matter in the Animator how the `AnimationClip` asset is called ... what matters is how the **states** in your `AnimatorController` asset are called .. maybe they match in the first but not the second animator ..?

Comment: Also the `.` in the names might be an issue ... usually the animator will treat those as the layer name! as in e.g. `"Base Layer.Clip Name"` .. see [`Animator.Play](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html)!!  => it is probably trying to find a layer called `CultistLv` .. it doesn't so it internally returns an index `-1` and then throws an exception which is printed as the warning you get